# Java 9: Console and PrintStream issue

Tags: java, javafx, console, printstream

I'm trying to get the content of the console and append it to a JavaFX TextArea.
I've found various examples all around StackOverflow, but all of them use a similar code to this:

```
@FXML
public void initialize() throws IOException {
    Console console = new Console();
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(console, true);
    System.setOut(ps);
    System.setErr(ps);
    System.err.flush();
    System.out.flush();
}
```

The issue is that the first two lines don't seem to be anymore accepted in Java 9. For the first one, I've solved my problem like this:

```
Console console = new Console();
```

becomes...

```
Console console = System.console();
```

Still, the PrintStream constructor doesn't accept anymore a java.io.Console object as an input, but only...

> Error:(124, 26) java: no suitable constructor found for PrintStream(java.io.Console,boolean)
>       constructor java.io.PrintStream.PrintStream(boolean,java.io.OutputStream) is not applicable
>         (argument mismatch; java.io.Console cannot be converted to boolean)
>       constructor java.io.PrintStream.PrintStream(java.io.OutputStream,boolean) is not applicable
>         (argument mismatch; java.io.Console cannot be converted to java.io.OutputStream)
>       constructor java.io.PrintStream.PrintStream(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) is not applicable
>         (argument mismatch; java.io.Console cannot be converted to java.lang.String)
>       constructor java.io.PrintStream.PrintStream(java.io.File,java.lang.String) is not applicable
>         (argument mismatch; java.io.Console cannot be converted to java.io.File)

Am I missing something?
For reference, I've used [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33894366/how-to-update-textareaconsolein-realtime-in-javafx-without-loosing-flow-or-fre/33915898#33915898).

Comment: It's not `System.console()` you see in those examples, it's a [custom Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981938/how-to-make-custom-java-javafx-console?rq=1).

Comment: I'll have a look at that question. Thank you for pointing out the culprit.
In any of the topic I've looked into was specified to use a Custom Console.